# Is there anyway to define objects in an array to numbers

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Im making a discord.js trivia command. but i dont get it. 
For so far everything is working, I want to make a converter for the Answers. Like: Answers is going to be a number instead a full answer.

I've searched everywhere but i cant find the correct answer to that.

The code:

```js
module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
    
    request.get("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&type=multiple", (err, response, body) => {
        let res = JSON.parse(body)
        let results = res.results[0]

        let answers = results.incorrect_answers;
        answers.push(results.correct_answer) // Pushes the correct answers in the incorrect answers array.


        // Entity decode loop
        var i;
        for (let i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
            entities.decode(answers[i])  
        }

     
        shuffle(answers) // Shuffles the answers in a random order.'

        console.log(answers)

        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor(`${message.author.username} trivia vraag`, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
            .setTitle(entities.decode(results.question))
            .setDescription(`1) ${answers[0]} \n 2) ${answers[1]} \n 3) ${answers[2]} \n4) ${answers[3]}`)
            .addField("Prijs", `\n ja wat Corona bacteriën.`, true)
            .addField(`Difficulty`, `\n ${results.difficulty}`, true)
            .addField(`Categorie`, `\n ${results.category}`, true)
            
            message.channel.send(embed)
            // console.log(results.question)
            // console.log(results.correct_answer)
    })



}

function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    while (0 !== currentIndex) {

        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;

        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
}
```

If someone can help me, please i need it haha If you dont get it, look up the picture i added. [The Discord message i got, i want to convert the full answer in to a number.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJsDA.png)

Kind regards,

Tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sort of confused but I think I got it,

`answers.findIndex(f => f === results.correct_answer);`

this would be 0 index based, so add 1 to it.